# MySQL problem joining 2 tables with UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I'm doing UNION in MySQL that I'm unable to troubleshoot for a while. 
Error says that

> syntax is incorrect around `t1.*`

Those 2 SELECTs work ok separately, checked. But UNION fails. I'm not custom to MySQL syntax, maybe something is wrong with that.

```sql
SELECT (
    t1.*,
    a.region_count
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        data_region,
        COUNT(*) AS region_count
      FROM
        t2
      GROUP BY
        data_region
    ) AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    t1
  ON
    t1.values_att0 = a.data_region
  WHERE
    t1.name_0 = 'region'
) AS b

UNION

SELECT (
  t1.*,
  c.age_gen_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      data_dage,
      data_gen,
      COUNT(*) AS age_gen_count
    FROM
      t2
    GROUP BY
      data_dage,
      data_gen
  ) AS c
  LEFT JOIN
    t1
  ON
    t1.values_att0 = c.data_dage AND
    t1.id_question_1 = c.data_gen
  WHERE
    t1.name_0 = 'age' AND 
    t1.q_name_1 = 'gen'
)
```

Comment: `UNION [ALL|DISTINCT]` glues two queries together. That means the rows are put together. For this to happen the columns must match. In your query, however, the first query to glue returns two columns and the second three. This cannot work. Please show sample data and expected result, so we see what you want the result to look like.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  What should I use if I want to merge them together anyway? NULLs will be present where there's no data but that's ok.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner btw I have same number of columns since in second SELECT shows count for combinations of attributes not for each of them individually.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I misread this. Then zessx' query should work for you. (But you'd want `UNION ALL` and either inner joins or the where clauses moved to the on clauses in order to make the outer joins work).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner exactly what happened when I used UNION ALL and removed few other mistakes :) . Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using parenthesis around your `SELECT` field, this is your syntax error origin (the `UNION` is not the cause). Just remove them:

```sql
SELECT 
  t1.*,
  a.region_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      data_region,
      COUNT(*) AS region_count
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY data_region
  ) AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN t1 
  ON  t1.values_att0 = a.data_region
WHERE t1.name_0 = 'region'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
  t1.*,
  c.age_gen_count
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      data_dage,
      data_gen,
      COUNT(*) AS age_gen_count
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY data_dage, data_gen
  ) AS c
LEFT JOIN t1 
  ON  t1.values_att0 = c.data_dage 
  AND t1.id_question_1 = c.data_gen
WHERE t1.name_0 = 'age' 
  AND t1.q_name_1 = 'gen'
```

Comment: So I should remove all parenthesis or just outer ones?

Comment: Just the outer one, I'm editing to show the whole query.

Comment: I changed query following your advice and now I get : #1054 - Unknown column 'a.region_count' in 'field list'

Comment: Please change UNION to UNION ALL since that's what worked in the end. You might want to also change a.region_count to a.region_count as attribute_count since this is same field showing counts for both table attributes.

Comment: Nice catch for `UNION ALL` ;)